# How to close a tab in Chrome that refuses to close?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I came across this interesting problem where I got redirected to some stupid spam site, I clicked the x to close the tab, but it instantly reappeared.

I tried closing it through task manager, through Chrome's task manager, nothing seemed to be able to close it for good.

How can I close it?

Comment: On what OS were you using exactly? The Chrome OS or Chrome web browser on Windows or another OS?

Comment: Just FYI... If this is Windows, you can just kill Chrome.exe from Windows Task Manager or using `TASKKILL /F /IM "Chrome.exe"` and close all instances of Chome and then just reopen it, do not restore the sesssion if it asks and then move on. If something like that happens to Chrome when I'm browsing the web, I want Chrome closed entirely and not just the suspected tab that's causing the erratic behavior.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT the chrome browser in windows 10. I assume that closing the entire chrome would work but there are situations where you wouldn't want to close all your other tabs. I love having many tabs open and always just restore my session, I'd be very sad if I had to close them all.

Comment: @Jedi yes I tried that and it didn't work, a dialog would flash asking if I wanted to leave the page or something but then the page would just reload, even if I killed the process from windows task manager it would reappear.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some code or something that is triggered when the tab is closed that opens a new tab of the same page.

To get around this go to the developer tools through the menu or via the hotkey (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>). Click the elements tab and then delete all the HTML.

You should now be able to close the tab without it popping up again.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Javascript and then closing the tab should work.

Go to settings in Chrome and choose "Show advanced settings".

Under Privacy there is a "Content settings" link where you can enable and disable javascript.